# Find $B$ in $\Big(\tan\Big(x+\frac{\pi}{2}\Big)-\Gamma(\sin(x))\Big)<C+(\pi-x)B$ around $\pi$

Tags: limits, trigonometry, inequality, gamma-function, constants

Thinking about a recent question of Claude Leibovici I come across the limit :

$$\lim_{x\to \pi^{-}}\Big(\tan\Big(x+\frac{\pi}{2}\Big)-\Gamma(\sin(x))\Big)=\gamma$$

Proof of the limit above :

It's equivalent to :

$$\lim_{x\to \pi^{-}}\Big(-\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}-\Gamma(\sin(x))\Big)=\gamma$$

With the substitution $y=\sin(x)$ we got :

$$\lim_{y\to 0^{+}}\Big(-\frac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}{y}-\Gamma(y)\Big)=\gamma$$

Now we use the fact :

$$\Gamma(y)=\frac{1}{y}-\gamma+(6\gamma^2+\pi^2)y+O(y^2)$$

The limit becomes :

$$\lim_{y\to 0^{+}}\Big(-\frac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}{y}-(\frac{1}{y}-\gamma)\Big)=\gamma$$

Wich is not hard to solve.

Now I would like to prove :

$$\Big(\tan\Big(x+\frac{\pi}{2}\Big)-\Gamma(\sin(x))\Big)<C+(\pi-x)B \quad (1)$$

for $3<x<\pi$ and the $C,B$ are positive constants.

I think we can use the limit describes aboves .

Question :

Is there a nice way to prove the inequality $(1)$ and find $B$ ?

Thanks in advance .

Regards Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it composing Taylor expansion and get for
$$y=\tan\Big(x+\frac{\pi}{2}\Big)-\Gamma(\sin(x))$$ $$y=\gamma -\frac{6+6 \gamma ^2+\pi ^2}{12} (\pi-x )+\frac{4 \zeta (3)+2 \gamma ^3+\gamma  \pi ^2}{12} (\pi-x
   )^2 +O\left((\pi-x )^3\right)$$

Comment: Well that's right !Thanks dear Claude Leibovici

Comment: @c-love-garlic. You are very welcome !

Comment: Could the big-oh constant cause problems?

Comment: @martycohen. Not really if we stay close to $3$. The coefficient of the next term is $$\frac{-480 \gamma  \zeta (3)-60-60 \gamma ^4+20 \pi ^2-9 \pi ^4-60 \gamma ^2
   \left(\pi ^2-2\right)}{1440}\approx -0.86$$